# mvn eclipse:eclipse failing after adding apache cxf dependencies

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I added maven dependencies for apache cxf to write web services in my project. After I add them, my unable to build my project or execute eclipse:eclipse. I am getting the following error while running the command.

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) on project CaseInstall: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]
```

I am using STS 3.2.0 and maven 3.1.1 version.

These are the dependencies I added,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
          <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
          <version>2.7.7</version>
       </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Did anyone face the same problem?

UPDATE:

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) on project CaseInstall: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse failed: For artifac
t {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse (default-cli) on project CaseInstall: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
n-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:317)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:152)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:555)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:214)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:158)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.9:eclipse failed: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:115)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.artifact.InvalidArtifactRTException: For artifact {null:null:null:jar}: The groupId cannot be empty.
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.validateIdentity(DefaultArtifact.java:130)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.DefaultArtifact.<init>(DefaultArtifact.java:123)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:157)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:111)
        at org.apache.maven.artifact.factory.DefaultArtifactFactory.createArtifact(DefaultArtifactFactory.java:39)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.LegacyRepositorySystem.createArtifact(LegacyRepositorySystem.java:119)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.initProject(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:604)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:160)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:312)
        at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:270)
        at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieveRelocatedProject(MavenMetadataSource.java:578)
        at org.apache.maven.project.artifact.MavenMetadataSource.retrieve(MavenMetadataSource.java:191)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.resolver.DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.java:532)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.resolver.DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.recurse(DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.resolver.DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.collect(DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.java:144)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.resolver.DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.collect(DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.java:100)
        at org.apache.maven.repository.legacy.resolver.DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.collect(DefaultLegacyArtifactCollector.java:782)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.ide.AbstractIdeSupportMojo.doDependencyResolution(AbstractIdeSupportMojo.java:560)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.ide.AbstractIdeSupportMojo.execute(AbstractIdeSupportMojo.java:507)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
```

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.coder</groupId>
    <artifactId>WebserviceDemo</artifactId>
    <name>WebserviceDemo</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.7</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        <cxf.version>2.7.7</cxf.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
         <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
         <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
         <artifactId>org.springframework.test</artifactId>
         <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
       </dependency>
       <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
   <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.1</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
   <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
   <version>1.3</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.184428</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>20030825.183949</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
</dependency>
            <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
           <!-- Drools -->
           <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
         <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
         <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
        <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Beanutils -->

    <dependency>
 <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
 <version>1.8.3</version>
</dependency>
     <!-- apache cxf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
          <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
          <version>${cxf.version}</version>
       </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
                <configuration>
                    <forkMode>always</forkMode>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7.7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources-proposal</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>src/main/java-generated</sourceRoot>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/service.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>com.coder.service</extraarg>
                                        <extraarg>-autoNameResolution</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/java-generated</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
            </build>
            <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.release</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.external</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - External Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/external</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.milestone</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - SpringSource Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>com.springsource.repository.bundles.snapshot</id>
            <name>SpringSource Enterprise Bundle Repository - Snapshot Releases</name>
            <url>http://repository.springsource.com/maven/bundles/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
<repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.maven.release</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.maven.milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>repository.springframework.maven.snapshot</id>
            <name>Spring Framework Maven Snapshot Repository</name>
            <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>jboss</id>
            <name>JBoss repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

UPDATE: **Could someone help me on this, please!!!**

Comment: mvn -e for more detail

Comment: updated my questions with more details

Comment: paste your pom.xml plz, seems sth wrong in pom

Comment: FYI `maven-eclipse-plugin` is obsolete. Use `m2e` Eclipse plugin instead.

Comment: @PavelHoral okay let me try it :)

Comment: after removing `maven-eclipse-plugin` from my pom, i get the same error :(

Comment: @coder seems work fine for me try to clean up mvn repo let mvn redownload them

Comment: no luck, getting the same error :|

Comment: Can anyone help me on this please??

Comment: The `pom.xml` you posted works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the groupId on a couple of plugins.
I had this problem once as well.
Try adding it to them. (You will have to look it up for what each is (the clean one is probably org.apache.maven.plugins )

Just from looking briefly I can see that it is missing from:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
        </additionalProjectnatures>
        <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
        </additionalBuildcommands>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <filesets>
                <fileset>
                    <directory>src/main/java-generated</directory>
                </fileset>
            </filesets>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

So they would (possibly) become:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
    <configuration>
        <additionalProjectnatures>
            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
        </additionalProjectnatures>
        <additionalBuildcommands>
            <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
        </additionalBuildcommands>
        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
        <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <filesets>
            <fileset>
                <directory>src/main/java-generated</directory>
            </fileset>
        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Good luck with it!

Comment: Tried this but no luck :(